# Google Spreadsheet SUMIF Date Comparison

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get this aggregate date comparison working, and I thought I understood the syntax, but it's clearly not working.  Can anyone correct the formula for me?

I'm trying to sum up the amounts in column I, where the date in H is prior to the date in A

My formula is  `=SUMIF(H$2:H,H$2:H<A4, I$2:I)`

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just a small error with your [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240293) syntax:

`=SUMIF(H$2:H;"<"&A4;I$2:I)`

Comment: This helped me, where I wanted to compare to today:  `=SUMIF(A10:A26, "<"&NOW(), B10:B26)`  *(referencing a function instead of a cell address)*

Comment: Semicolons as argument separators... I'll never understand why Google would try to localise a programming language...